# a cross-reference to a table in MS word, takes the table itself to my text

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, cross-reference

In MS Word 2013, I have a table and an auto-caption under it "Table 1: ...". Then I go further in my text and chose the following choice and click on the insert

[image]

Then MS word takes the table itself before the Label and Number! I supposed that maybe it is because my table and caption are not separated; so, I inserted a line between them

[image]

but no difference.
How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1- Select a part of your document simple text.

2- Chose the "format painter"

[image]

3- Select your table and whatever you would like not to come.